# Why won't my Mac start?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a MacBook Pro 13 inch and something really weird happened.

Earlier today it worked perfectly fine, a few hourslater I tried to turn it on and it was stuck at the startup. It has a little progress bar and the spinning wheel. I have tried the safe boot but it won't work, either.

Comment: Take a picture of the progress bar. There is only one kind of progress bar that can show itself before boot and that is when a SMC upgrade is taking place. If a SMC upgrade failed for some reason you might need to take it to an Apple Store under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to take it to apple if you have it under warranty. They will most likely go in the back and reset it and most likely that will fix it. I had a USB error not that long ago, so I took it to Apple. They reset my computer, and it fixed it. Nothing was deleted/lost, and rebooted perfectly fine. Only problem is it runs a tiny bit slow once you reboot, but it will work itself out after a bit of use.